# When using createElement appendChild how can i access them latter?

Tags: javascript

When i create an element using createElement then appendChild i can't access them using eventListener.

In this case

```
<div class="row">
            <ul class="maldito mt-5">
            </ul>
        </div>
```

After i add the li element i can't target it with eventListener

```
var $ul = document.querySelector('.maldito');
var $li = $ul.querySelectorAll('li');

        (function(){
            var x = 0;
            while ( x < 2) {
                x++;
                var addLi = document.createElement('li');
                $ul.appendChild(addLi);
            }
            $li = $ul.querySelectorAll('li');
            for ( var i = 0; i < $li.length; i++ ){
                $li[i].textContent = "Some text";
            }
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                for ( var i = 0; i < addLi.length; i ){
                    addLi[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                        this.classList.add('active');
                    })
                }
            })
        })()
```

Comment: In this example its not working because of the index in addLi, i wanted to know if their was something similar to this to use for more then one element.

Comment: `addLi` is not an array, it's a single element. What do you want to iterate?

Answer (score 0):

You should either keep a reference to the element or access the element the event handler was attached to through [`Event#currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");

const words = [
  "hello",
  "world",
  "foo",
  "bar"
];

// Map words to array of HTMLElements
const wordElements = words.map(w => {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerHTML = w;
  return el;
});

// Append elements after we have created them
// Even though "el" reference is gone
wordElements.forEach(we => app.appendChild(we));

// Even add event listener later
wordElements.forEach(we => {
  we.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log(`Through el reference: ${we.innerHTML}`);
    console.log(`Through currentTarget: ${e.currentTarget.innerHTML}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: But in this case it has one element so the createElement still has the same id. In my case i have more then one element and i can only find the last one with eventListener.

Comment: @Leo I'm not sure I understand.  Take a look at my edit and see if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push your new li element into an array (`lis` on my example)

```js
var $ul = document.querySelector('.maldito');
var $li = $ul.querySelectorAll('li');

let lis = [];// li elements array

        (function(){
            var x = 0;
            while ( x < 2) {
                x++;
                var addLi = document.createElement('li');
                $ul.appendChild(addLi);
                lis.push(addLi);// push the li element into the lis array
            }
           // $li = $ul.querySelectorAll('li');
            for ( var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ ){
                lis[i].textContent = "Some text";
            }
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
               //console.log(lis.length)
                for ( var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ ){
                    lis[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                        this.classList.add('active');
                    })
                }
            })
        })()
```

```css
.active{color:red}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <ul class="maldito mt-5">
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I guess `$li` is already trying to do just that, you might want to remove the duplication

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked, In this case would you consider accepting my answer?

Comment: Instead of pollute the global environment with variables like `let lis = [];`, instead pass an empty array to the closure, e.g. `(function(lis){...})([]);`